When is thickening of scheme Cohen-Macaulay?
I have the following question.
All schemes below are assumed to be Notherian, and we can also assume that these schemes are varieties over some field. Suppose there is Cohen-Macaulay closed subscheme $Z$ on regular scheme $X$. Is there exists some thickening of $Z$ in $X$ which is Cohen-Macaulay? And what if we assume $Z$ to be regular too? In particular, if such regular $Z$ contains point $x$, is there Cohen-Macaulay thickening of $Z$ in $X$ containing $\text{Spec}\left( \mathcal{O}_{X, x}/\mathfrak{m}_x^n\right)$, where $\mathfrak{m}_x$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathcal{O}_{X, x}$? What if $X$ and $Z$ are regular projective varieties?
I tried to think about this problem locally. Let $R$ be regular Notherian ring containing a field, $\mathfrak{p}$ be such prime ideal that $R/\mathfrak{p}$ is regular and $\mathfrak{p}\subset \mathfrak{m}$ for some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. We can consider symbolic power $\mathfrak{p}^{(m)}$ for some large $m$. By result of Hochster and Huneke in “Comparison of symbolic and ordinary powers of ideals” $\mathfrak{p}^{(m)}\subset \mathfrak{p}^n$ for $m \gg n$ and then $\mathfrak{p}^{(m)}\subset \mathfrak{m}^n$, so non zero divisor in $R/\mathfrak{p}$ lifts to non zero divisor in $R/\mathfrak{p}^{(m)}$, but it seems that regular sequence can’t be lifted to a regular sequence.
Of particular interest is the case when $X$ is regular projective 3-dimensional variety, $Z$ is 2-dimensional regular projective in $X$ containing point $x$.

If $X$ and $Z$ are smooth over the base field, then $Z$ is locally cut out by a subset of a regular system of parameters of $X$, i.e. in the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{x, X}$ we have $\mathfrak{m}_x = (f_1, \ldots, f_n)$ where $n = \dim X$ and $I(Z) = (f_1, \ldots, f_k)$ where $k$ is the codimension of $Z$ in $X$.
Then the sequence $f_{k+1}, \ldots, f_n$ remains regular on $\mathcal{O}_{x, X} / I(Z)^d$ for every exponent $d$, since it cuts the dimension down to $0$. So, yes, the thickening is Cohen-Macaulay in this case. I don't know what to expect in the non-regular case.
